# Unable to get host-only network in Ubuntu-mini (bionic-18.04) guest

Tags: networking, lubuntu, windows-10, docker, ubuntu-minimal

I am trying to install a bare-minimum (mini) Ubuntu (18.04) guest on Virtualbox v6.0.2 on Windows 10 Pro (Version 1809 Build 17763.253), so that I could have Docker (Community Edition) installed inside guest.  By this I could avoid installing Hyper-V on Windows 10 - the experience of which was pretty bad earlier

The problem is, I am just getting the NAT interface on the guest, with which I am able to access the Internet but not the host-only interface.  What I expected was, when I run the 'ifconfig', I hoped to see another interface (apart from NAT and loopback) with 192.168.. IP.

This seems to be a problem only with Ubuntu-18.04-mini guest whereas Lubuntu-18.10 guest doesn't - Host-only interface is installed along with NAT and loopback, "out-of-the-box".

Kindly note that I had taken care to add the Host-only interface on the VBox side before I even installed the (mini) guest.  Please help in pointing out where I am going wrong / missing.

Thanks in advance,
Vatsan

Comment: Do you get the host only interface if you install the full Ubuntu rather than the mini version?

Comment: @user68186 Yes, with the full Lubuntu 18.10 guest, I am getting NAT, Host-only and Loopback, without me fiddling in the guest later